# jQuery Font Selector: show&hide with focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a jQuery Font Selector in my project but I have some troubles to achieve it. I'm using the source code I found here [jQuery Font Selector](http://www.fullfatcode.com/2011/04/10/jquery-font-selector-version-2/)
You can see the [demo here](http://www.fullfatcode.com/examples/jqfontselector/)

Everything is working great, except the author of this code hasn't included a function that close the "scrolling menu" if we clicked anywhere else on the screen. You're forced to choose something inside that list for this list to close.

I'm going to paste the code here so it'll be easier to explain.

```
/**
* Font selector plugin
*/
jQuery.fn.fontSelector = function() {

var fonts = new Array(
'Arial,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
'Arial Black,Arial Black,Gadget,sans-serif',
/* other fonts */);

  return this.each(function(){

    // Get input field
    var sel = this;

    // Add a ul to hold fonts
    var ul = $('<ul class="fontselector"></ul>');
    $('body').prepend(ul);
    $(ul).hide();

    jQuery.each(fonts, function(i, item) {

      $(ul).append('<li><a href="#" class="font_' + i + '" style="font-family: ' + item + '">' + item.split(',')[0] + '</a></li>');

      // Prevent real select from working
      $(sel).focus(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        // Show font list
        $(ul).show();

        // Position font list
        $(ul).css({ top:  $(sel).offset().top + $(sel).height() + 4,
                left: $(sel).offset().left});

        // Blur field
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
      });

      $(ul).find('a').click(function() {
         var font = fonts[$(this).attr('class').split('_')[1]];
         $(sel).val(font);
         $(ul).hide();
        return false;
      });
    });

  });

 }
```

From here I tried to modify the code, like adding `$(ul).hide();` inside the blur function... Works **BUT** that i don't want the input to be **manually** editable. I don't want the user to be able to modify the content of the input except by selecting a font.

I hope you're not to confused with what I'm asking !

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Some changes after discussion:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahkEv/4/

Add the following inside `jQuery.fn.fontSelector = function() {`

```
$("body").click(function(){        
   $(".fontselector").hide();          
});
```

Change `$(sel).focus` to

```
$(sel).click(function(ev) {
```

and add the following to `$(ul).find('a').click(function(ev) {`

```
ev.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Where exactly am i supposed to put this code? Inside the `$(sel).focus(...)` ?
Because what happends is that the list shows up and hide immediatly.

Comment: the 2nd piece should be inside of `$(ul).find('a').click(function() {` and the first part should be outside of any of the other stuff.

Comment: if you can put your code into a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) I'll play around with it and see if I can find what's wrong.

Comment: I've put my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ahkEv/1/ - I'm trying to make jQuery work with Fiddle but basically, my code is there. Thanks again